# no se como agregar sonido y nesesito agregar sonido a mi juego

Tags: java, mensajes, sonido

quiero agregar un sonido a mi juego de java pero no se como hacerlo(no se si sera porque hay un minimo de tiempo que dure el sonido), pero con todas la maneras que me han dicho para hacerlo no se escuchaba nada muchas gracias.
esto es lo que e provado poner

```
public Clip clip;
public String ruta="Musica/wins/";
public void sound(String Archivo) {
try{
clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStr
clip.start();
  }catch (Exception e) {
 }
}
sound("wins");
```

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega lo que has tratado para poder ayudarte en base a lo que tienes. ;)

Comment: este codigo esta incompleto.. y mas alla de eso, que pasa si sacas el catch, hay algun error???